# How to acess json parameter in json file

Tags: jquery, json

I want to know how can I get the parameter value in json file.

Here I am requesting my elements.json file.

```
$.getJSON('elements.json?version=2.1',function(data){
 console.log(data);
});
```

element.json look like this:

```
{"elements": {
    "Headers":[
        {"url":"elements/header1.html","height":700},
        {"url":"elements/header2.html","height":700},
    ],
    }
}
```

I want to print the value of version like this:

```
elements/header1.html?version=2.1
```

How can I achieve this or is there any alternate way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you want to print this value? do you need it in success handler code?

Comment: When I console the response then the version value should be there like I mentioned above.

Comment: sorry but still unclear. Could you please update your JS code and show us where you are putting the `console.log` statement.

Comment: your question is very unclear

Comment: Just updated. FYI, I just want  that version value inside my elements.json file,that's it.

Comment: @Rahul how does it help you this version at the end of the url?

Comment: .json file is just a resource file. It never gets executed; I mean it doesn't hold the code. So its not possible to read the incoming version and append it before response goes back to client JS code. What you can do is you can have `version` variable declared just before `$.getJSON(` call and use the same to append it to urls which you can read from json response.

Comment: I guess you guys are right. I just learned new thing. we cannot print the value in json file. thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation:

```js
var data = {"elements": {
    "Headers":[
        {"url":"elements/header1.html","height":700},
        {"url":"elements/header2.html","height":700},
    ],
    }
};
var version = '?version=2.1'
var version_url  = data.elements["Headers"][0].url+version
console.log(version_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I Dont't reall know what exactly you want but if you want a string like that

elements/header1.html?version=2.1

then you can just fetch the data first and then concatenate the '?version=2.1' with the result.

```
$.getJSON('elements.json',function(data){
  var desired = data.elements["Headers"][0]['url'] + '?version=2.1';
  console.log(desired);
  });
```